# Access this property from forEach EventListener

Tags: javascript

So, I've a bunch of a.md-trigger class that lets attached with popup. Every a.md-trigger has attributes such as postid="12" ext-data-id="55" . I have a popUpLoader() function that lets me open a popup when clicked on md-trigger. 
To open the popUpLoader() I need to get those data attributes. 
Current code looks something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.md-trigger').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
popUpLoader();
  })
})
```

And the popUpLoader() looks like this:

```
function popUpLoader(){
        e.preventDefault();
       var internalURL =e.getAttribute("postid");
  //here is ajax request something like this: 
$.ajax({
URL: internalURL 
 }) bla bla 


}
```

So, there I need that internalURL where every a.md-trigger has its own postid attribute value. 
How can I access $this feature in forEach click eventListener?

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying that `popUpLoader()` is the same thing as `newsClickAlgo()`? And you don't seem to be passing the event in, so you won't be able to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply access the attributes using [`Element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), since you are not using the standard HTML5 `data-` attribute:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.md-trigger').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(item.getAttribute('postid'), item.getAttribute('ext-data-id'));
  })
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" postid="1" ext-data-id="999">Trigger (postid: 1, extDataId: 999)</a>
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" postid="2" ext-data-id="998">Trigger (postid: 2, extDataId: 998)</a>
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" postid="3" ext-data-id="997">Trigger (postid: 3, extDataId: 997)</a>
```

Based on your update code, the reason why `e` is not accessible in `popUpLoader()` is because you are not passing the event into the function. Also, to reference the element that triggered the event, you need to use `e.target`. There are two solutions to this:

## 1. Call `popUpLoader` directly in the event listener

```js
function popUpLoader(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const internalURL = e.target.getAttribute("postid");
  console.log(internalURL);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.md-trigger').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', popUpLoader);
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" postid="1" ext-data-id="999">Trigger (postid: 1, extDataId: 999)</a>
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" postid="2" ext-data-id="998">Trigger (postid: 2, extDataId: 998)</a>
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" postid="3" ext-data-id="997">Trigger (postid: 3, extDataId: 997)</a>
```

## 2. Pass the `event` object when invoking `popUpLoader`

```js
function popUpLoader(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const internalURL = e.target.getAttribute("postid");
  console.log(internalURL);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.md-trigger').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => popUpLoader(e));
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" postid="1" ext-data-id="999">Trigger (postid: 1, extDataId: 999)</a>
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" postid="2" ext-data-id="998">Trigger (postid: 2, extDataId: 998)</a>
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" postid="3" ext-data-id="997">Trigger (postid: 3, extDataId: 997)</a>
```

---

I would recommend that you start using HTML5 `data-` attribute if you have the ability to update the markup, because all these attributes will then be uniformly accessible via [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset):

```js
function popUpLoader(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const internalURL = e.target.dataset.postId;
  console.log(internalURL);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.md-trigger').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', popUpLoader);
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" data-post-id="1" data-ext-id="999">Trigger (postId: 1, extId: 999)</a>
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" data-post-id="2" data-ext-id="998">Trigger (postId: 2, extId: 998)</a>
<a href="#" class="md-trigger" data-post-id="3" data-ext-id="997">Trigger (postId: 3, extId: 997)</a>
```